# In R, is it possible to create a new object inside a function and pass it to the parent environment?

Tags: r

The function would look something like:

```
function(input, FUN, output) {

    output <- FUN(input)

    return(input)

}
```

Where output is an unquoted name of an object to be created.

Let's skip the part where this is probably a bad idea: is this sort of thing possible? How would you go about doing it?

Comment: The returned object will have the name you assign it to. Its name within the function is irrelevant.

Comment: If you need objects that can retain state, consider using reference classes or R6 classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Clean* code would just return it.

But you have other options:

- the `<<-` operator
- the `assign()` function where you can list the environment to assign to

Here is a trivial example:

```
R> foo <- function(x=21) { y <<- 2*x; return(3*x) }
R> foo(10)
[1] 30
R> y
[1] 20
R>
```

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Try this:

```
fun <- function(input, FUN, output = "output", envir = parent.frame()) {
    envir[[output]] <- FUN(input)
    input
}

fun(4, sqrt)
## [1] 4
output
## [1] 2
```

Note that if hardcoding the output variable name to `output` is ok then the assignment could be written:

```
envir$output <- FUN(input)
```

**2)** Another possibility if you want to output both the input and output yet avoiding side effects is to return both in a list:

```
fun2 <- function(input, FUN, output = "output") 
  setNames(list(input, FUN(input)), c("input", output))

fun2(4, sqrt)
```

giving:

```
$input
[1] 4

$output
[1] 2
```

**2a)** A variation of this is:

```
devtools::install_github("ggrothendieck/gsubfn") 
library(gsubfn)  # list[...] <- ...
list[input, output] <- fun2(sqrt)
```

giving:

```
> input
[1] 4
> output
[1] 2
```

**3)** Yet another possibility is to pass the input in an attribute:

```
fun3 <- function(input, FUN) {
  out <- FUN(input)
  attr(out, "input") <- input
  out
}

fun3(4, sqrt)
```

giving:

```
[1] 2
attr(,"input")
[1] 4
```